# PHP MySQL Management

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry guys, I'm no master of MySQL and I've only just begun learning this but the first thing getting me frustrated right now is adding a field that is a "Longtext" and it automatically goes PRIMARY and INDEXED and also UNIQUE.

That field I'm talking about is for storing huge amount of characters, basically it is where I plan to store 1 page of texts which is why I need it to be "Longtext". Problem is no matter what I do I can't remove Unique or Indexed or Primary from fields that are "Longtext". I do not want to remove it through queries, I am trying to remove it through PHPMyAdmin since I don't want to do the SQL query for this task only. I keep clicking on the fields and clicking Index or Primary or Unique but it never changes, I'm getting so frustrated :(

Comment: How are you adding the column? Are you using some kind of tool? A simple `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD newcolumn LONGTEXT` will most definitely not cause it to be primary or unique. Something else is wrong in your toolchain.

Comment: Post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtablename`.

Comment: THat's why I don't like the SQL query section of it, I'm not familiar on that part and would need to jump to another learning topic.:p I am doing it simply through PHPMyAdmin without using any queries or the SQL tab. Just manual management through PHPMyAdmin, there's a button there to add 1 column then I hit GO button

Comment: I can't help with phpmyadmin, which I never use. But if you do need to create your column now before figuring out what the heck is wrong with PMA, this is the query to do it:  `ALTER TABLE yourtablename ADD yournewcolumn LONGTEXT` Add `NOT NULL` to the end if you don't want to permit nulls.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will wait for more ideas for a few more hours and if none, I will do your suggestion. It means I have to learn that section of MySQL first and I really hope I wouldn't have to lol

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is with PHPMyAdmin, rather than MySQL, because what you describe does not sound like any behavior of MySQL. (To find out if it's a MySQL problem, we'd really need to see the actual SQL statements being run, what is recorded in the information_schema tables/views, etc.)

I understand you don't want to run the SQL statements that are actually required by MySQL.

It sounds as if the developers of PHPMyAdmin didn't want to run them either.